# Regular Expressions: find same words in a dictionary in a line

Tags: regex, dictionary, editor

I have a dictionary in a txt file with the following format:

```
house house$casa | casa, vivienda, hogar | edificio, casa | vivienda
```

The $ sign separates the term of the translation.

I want to locate the dictionary words that appear several times at the same line, by a regular expression with a text editor, such as Sublimetext, Notepad++,... I do not want a php function because I have to check manually if I have to remove those repeated words. In the above example, the regular expression should find house, casa and vivienda. My goal would be to obtain the following result:

```
house$casa | vivienda, hogar | edificio
```

I have tried using the following expression but it does not work properly:

```
(\b\w+\b)\W+\1
```

Comment: You will not be able to do this with regex alone. Get used to the idea to do it with a programming language.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, here is a crude example of how to do this in Python:

```py
import re

def distinct_words(block, seen, delim):
    """ makes a list of words distinct, given a set of words seen earlier """

    unique_words = []

    for word in re.split(delim, block):
        if not word in seen:
            seen[word] = True
            unique_words.append(word)

    return unique_words

def process_line(line):
    """ removes all duplicate words from a dictionary line """

    # safeguard
    if '$' not in line: return line

    # split line at the '$'
    original, translated = line.split('$')

    # make original words distinct
    distinct_original = distinct_words(original, {}, r' +')

    # make translated words distinct, but keep block structure

    # split the translated part at '|' into blocks
    # split each block at ', ' into words
    seen = {}
    distinct_translated = [
        distinct_list for distinct_list in (
            distinct_words(block, seen, r', +') for block in (
                re.split(r'\s*\|\s*', translated)
            )
        )
        if len(distinct_list) > 0
    ]

    # put everything back together again
    part_original = ' '.join(distinct_original)
    part_translated = [', '.join(block) for block in distinct_translated]
    part_translated = ' | '.join(part_translated)
    result = part_original + '$' + part_translated

    return result

def process_dictionary(filename):
    """ processes a dictionary text file, modifies the file in place """

    lines = open(filename,'r').readlines()    
    lines_out = [process_line(line) for line in lines]
    contents_out = '\n'.join(lines_out)
    open(filename,'w').write(contents_out)
```

Apparently you would call `process_dictionary()`, like this:

```py
process_dictionary('dict_en_es.txt')
```

But for the sake of the example, assume you have a single line:

```py
line = "house house$casa | casa, vivienda, hogar | edificio, casa | vivienda"
line_out = process_line(line)
print line_out
```

which prints the wanted result:

```
house$casa | vivienda, hogar | edificio
```